# Can one state the idea of collinearity in linear algebra terms?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

The elementary geometry book I have states:

*Points that lie on the same line are called collinear.*

*In order for us to say that a point is between two other points, all three of the points must be collinear.*

Can I state this in terms of linear algebra?

I just feel there should be a non-geometric way to say this. (Could closure axioms be useful?)

Comment: "The difference (vectors) between any two pairs of points are linearly dependent". Do you mean something like that?

Comment: I think something like that, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In linear algebra, a straight line in Euclidean space is a linear mapping.A set of lines are each subspaces of 2 or 3 dimensional Euclidean space, that constitutes a system of n linear equations in m unknowns in turn which can be represented by an m X n  matrix. Consider that in any system of linear equations,each of which is a straight line, the system has either one unique solution ( the lines intersect at a single unique point) , no solutions( all lines are parallel and there are no intersecting points or they lie on multiple intersecting lines that are in 2 different sets of lines) or infinitely many solutions ( all points lie on the same line or equivalently,all lines coincide in the space).So if a number of points lie on the same line in either the plane or 3-space, then collinear points can be thought of as solutions in a system of n linear equations in m unknowns which has infinitely many solutions.

Comment: @M.Vinay Good point,but I was referring when the points lie on a single set of lines. But strictly speaking,yes,you are correct.